# Curator Framework or?

Tags: design-patterns, apache-curator

We have a microservice architecture, wherein we have multiple nodes running the same microservice. I have to schedule a job to be executed once a day by only one node. What is the best way of achieving this? Some of the options I have researched into are:

1. Curator framework. My microservice is taken care of by Docker Swarm, so I don't need ZooKeeper. Using the Curator framework will introduce a new dependency on ZooKeeper and I don't like that.
2. Row based. Whichever node first gets to start working on the job flips the switch and the other nodes see that it is in progress and don't work on it. No new dependencies added.

Can the leader election with the Curator framework be only done when the scheduled job has to run? Or is there a need for the leader to be elected at all times?

Are there other options out there that I can look at? Am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't Socker Swarm include Consul somewhere? You could do the leader election with Consul.

Comment: what about retrying when the job fails? Will that be another recipe with Curator? I will take a look at Consul also. Curator Leadership selector is already used by other micro-services. I am wondering if it is an overkill to use Curator or should I just go with option 2?

Comment: If you have ZooKeeper in your system already use Curator for sure.

Comment: Can this be done using curator : Can the Leader election with curator framework be only done when the scheduled job has to run? Or is there a need for the leader to be elected at all times?

Comment: You can elect a leader only when needed, yes.